# How to integrate Zuul with Swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, netflix-zuul

I faced with some issue generating swagger documentaion in my microservices project. When I add zuul custom routings swagger documentation becames inconsistent.

Examples:

1. RestController:

> ```
>     @RestController
>     public class Controller {
>
>          @PostMapping("/foo")
>          public void foo() {}    
>     }
> ```

2. Zuul routings:

> ```
> zuul:
>   routes:
>     foo:
>       path: /bar/**
>       url: http://localhost:8080/foo
> ```

3. Swagger configuration

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableSwagger2
> public class SwaggerConfig {
>     @Bean
>     public Docket api() {
>         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
>                 .select()
>                 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package"))
>                 .build();
>     }
> }
> ```

- What I need: Swagger UI displays /bar endpoint
- What I get: Swagger UI displays /foo endpoint (and it's useless for frontend developers because they generates their components in runtime using swagger)

So, is there any solution how can I configure swagger or zuul to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 1):

We had to add zuul configuration in **application.yml** file.

```
# custom configuration - used by swagger to rename endpoints in documentation
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /api/uaa/api-docs

whitelistInternal:
  - method: GET
    path: '/api/**/api-docs'
  - method: GET
    path: '/swagger-ui.html'
  - method: GET
    path: '/swagger-resources/**'
```

Please, check lines that suit you.

This is an example how it can be done
https://dzone.com/articles/centralized-documentation-in-microservice-spring-b